# What hardware to use to mount a towel rack with a sliding pocket door directly behind the wall?

Tags: screws, fastener

all.

I want to install a 24" towel rack on a bathroom wall and I'm not able to use butterfly anchors or any of the usual type of anchors where the screws will be more than an inch deep into the wall. I can get away with using a butterfly anchor on one side (where the pocket door will not reach). But on the other side the pocket door will get in the way.

Is there any other type of mounting hardware that will be able to serve my needs? Given that this towel rack will be holding two body towels it will be holding a few pounds and this connection needs to be strong.

My one option could possibly be to cut out a piece of drywall in the adjacent room (which is a small bedroom that we'll eventually remodel and smooth out the knockout texture on the existing walls which I don't like) and actually use a butterfly anchor. Then once the towel rack is in place I can use a hacksaw or wire cutters to cut off the remaining excess of the screw that is holding the butterfly clamp in place. Thus, eliminating any long screw shafts that sick through the space that could damage or prevent my pocket door from operating. But I'm hoping not to have to go this route as that's a bit tedious. But it could be a last resort if necessary.

Comment: hang it from the ceiling :)

Comment: The problem isn't the weight of wet towels. The problem is the human using the towel bar as a grab bar when the floor is unexpectedly slippery. The only real solution is to attach to the studs (or other framing) somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If in North America, Toggler brand anchors will work. They have a plastic sleeve affair that pulls the anchor that’s inside the wall while you set the machine screw. All you need to do is cut the machine screw to length in advance. (Don’t forget to file the threads at the end so they attach easily. It might help to put a nut on the machine screw before cutting and spin the nut off, thus partly restoring threads.)

Eg: [Toggler, not an endorsement of Lowes](https://www.lowes.com/pd/TOGGLER-10-Pack-Assorted-Length-x-1-4-in-Dia-Toggle-Bolt-Drywall-Anchor-Screws-Included/3183831?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-hdw-_-ggl-_-PLA_HDW_126_Fastening-_-3183831-_-online-_-0-_-0&gbraid=0AAAAAD2B2W-jHoxVjaaoUSz_8tDpqXDFK&gbraid=0AAAAAD2B2W-jHoxVjaaoUSz_8tDpqXDFK&gclid=CjwKCAjwv-GUBhAzEiwASUMm4rSfeoeeiBD5O9Ai5V6thRuVYPmCl8e6nbXvmBN6zD2ztBk2qBrvbBoC_7kQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this will be my best option. Although Freeman provided a great answer it limits me to how high or low the wooden framing is located inside the wall. If it's not exactly at the height I'll need then it would alter my design in terms of placement of the rack.

Answer (score 1):

There is wooden framing around the pocket door, no? Move the towel bar left/right and up/down until that other end is over wood and screw it into the wood.

Sure, you won't be able to use your standard length screw that you'd use going into a standard 2x stud on edge, but you'll at least have some wood and drywall for the screw to bite into. This will eliminate the need for any anchor at all.

Comment: Or hang a piece of 1/2" painted plywood up first, then mount to that.

Comment: You'll be able to see the horizontal door frame rails with a light through the gap. They're roughly every 16". You can usually penetrate the wall 1-1/2" before concern of contact, but do verify visually. If the heights of the rails don't meet your needs, two finished vertical boards spanning them should do nicely.